# Is it possible to make a swap space(partition) in windows 8.1 like linux?

Tags: windows-8.1, swap

I'm using alot of ram on a daily basis and I know you have swap partitions in linux to help this, is it possible to do in windows 8.1 and if so, how? thanks

Comment: You can create a new partition and move part of your swapfile to it but it doesn't gain you anything *(noticeable)* afaik. On a modern system, I wouldn't expect the swap file to be hit that often if at all. If it is, you either have applications leaking memory or to little memory to begin with.

Comment: Yup, custom swap file size and relocation to a different partition are both possible and have been for many versions. You can also go to the lengths [this guy](http://www.nerdscene.com/2010/03/31/143/) did.

Comment: @Karan This looks great... If I move the swapfile to a partition on the same ssd as windows is installed, will it really not make a difference in performance because, "Doing this allows Windows to dump temp junk onto one drive while not having to interrupt reads or writes on the other drive."

Comment: SSDs don't have the same performance characteristics as HDDs, so moving the swap file to another location on the same SSD will IMO be useless.

Comment: If you intend to do this as a learning exercise, by all means go ahead. If it's not, your benefit/cost ratio *(cost being time spend)* will be very low. Unless your time is a penny worth, I wouldn't bother. How much ram are you talking about? Are you sure it's not the file system cache you see using all your ram *(which is a good thing)*. Have you verified using RAMMap from sysinternals?